# Android studio registration button isnt responsing a volley request

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio

i m trying to make registration script in android studio with volley library and PHP page. PHP pages are working fine, it has been tested. I have it on WEBSERVER like MySQL and connection is good and everything in there tested. Today i m trying to make some app but i want to have registration and login there. Could u tell me why nothing happens when i click on Registration button? Where do i have error in my code? I would really appreciate every help.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button reg_bn;
    EditText Name,Email,UserName,Password,ConPassword;
    String name,email,username,password,conpass;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    String reg_url = "https://prchy.ic.cz/register.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        reg_bn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn_reg);
        Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        UserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_user_name);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        ConPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_con_password);
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
        reg_bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               name = Name.getText().toString();
               email = Email.getText().toString();
               username = UserName.getText().toString();
               password = Password.getText().toString();
               conpass = ConPassword.getText().toString();
               if(name.equals("")||email.equals("")||username.equals("")||password.equals("")||conpass.equals(""))
               {
                   builder.setTitle("Něco se pokazilo...");
                   builder.setMessage("Prosím vyplňte všechny pole.");
                   displayAlert("input_error");
               }
               else {
                   if(!(password.equals(conpass)))
                   {
                       builder.setTitle("Něco se pokazilo...");
                       builder.setMessage("Vaše hesla se neshodují.");
                       displayAlert("input_error");
                   }
                   else {
                       StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, reg_url,
                               new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onResponse(String response) {
                                       try {
                                           JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                           JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                           String code = jsonObject.getString("code");
                                           String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
                                           builder.setTitle("Odpověď serveru...");
                                           builder.setMessage(message);
                                           displayAlert(code);
                                       } catch (JSONException e) {
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                           }
                       }){
                           @Override
                           protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                               Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                               params.put("name",name);
                               params.put("email",email);
                               params.put("user_name",username);
                               params.put("password",password);
                               return params;
                           }
                       };
                       MySingleton.getInstance(Register.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);


                   }
                   }
               }
            });

    }
    public void displayAlert(final String code)
    {
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if(code.equals("input_error"))
            {
                Password.setText("");
                ConPassword.setText("");
            }
            else if(code.equals("reg_success")){
                finish();
            }
            else if(code.equals("reg_failed")){
                Name.setText("");
                UserName.setText("");
                Password.setText("");
                ConPassword.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

And in my xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    tools:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.bongfinalapp.Register">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_name"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Vaše jméno"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reg_email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_email"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="E-Mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reg_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_user_name"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Přihlašovací jméno"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reg_password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_email"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.045" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_password"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Heslo"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reg_con_password"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_user_name"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.074" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bn_reg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registruj"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_con_password" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="144dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/reg_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bong" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_con_password"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Potvrď heslo"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bn_reg"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_password" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Show **MySingelton** class. add log for onError to check if you not receive error